# Perl incorrectly adding newline characters?

Tags: perl

This is my tab delimited input file

```
Name<tab>Street<tab>Address
```

This is how I want my output file to look like

```
Street<tab>Address<tab>Address
```

(yes duplicate the next two columns) My output file looks like this instead

```
Street<tab>Address
         <tab>Address
```

What is going on with perl? This is my code.

```
open (IN, $ARGV[0]);

open (OUT, ">output.txt");
while ($line = <IN>){

    chomp $line;
    @line=split/\t/,$line;

    $line[2]=~s/\n//g;
   print OUT $line[1]."\t".$line[2]."\t".$line[2]."\n";
}

close( OUT);
```

Comment: I think you might have a DOS file running on unix. try dos2unix on your input file

Comment: Side comment. I would avoid variables `$line` and `@line` maybe `@lineparts`

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $line;`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should *always*

- `use strict` and `use warnings` for even the most trivial programs. You will also need to declare each of your variables using `my` as close as possible to their first use
- use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open`
- check the success of *every* `open` call, and `die` with a string that includes `$!` to show the reason for the failure

Note also that there is no need to explicitly open files named on the command line that appear in `@ARGV`: you can just read from them using `<>`.

As others have said, it looks like you are reading a file of DOS or Windows origin on a Linux system. Instead of using `chomp`, you can remove *all* trailing whitespace characters from each line using `s/\s+\z//`. Since CR and LF both count as "whitespace", this will remove all line terminators from each record. Beware, however, that, if trailing space is significant or if the last field may be blank, then this will also remove spaces and tabs. In that case, `s/[\r\n]+\z//` is more appropriate.

This version of your program works fine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV = 'addr.txt';

open my $out, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;

while (<>) {
  s/\s+\z//;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  print $out join("\t", @fields[1, 2, 2]), "\n";
}

close $out or die $!;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know *beforehand* the origin of your data file, and know it to be a DOS-like file that terminates records with `CR LF`, you can use the `PerlIO` `crlf` layer when you open the file. Like this

```
open my $in, '<:crlf', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
```

then all records will appear to end in just `"\n"` when they are read on a Linux system.

A general solution to this problem is to install [`PerlIO::eol`](https://metacpan.org/module/PerlIO%3a%3aeol). Then you can write

```
open my $in, '<:raw:eol(LF)', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
```

and the line ending will *always* be `"\n"` regardless of the origin of the file, and regardless of the platform where Perl is running.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to eliminate not only the "\n" but also the "\r"???

```
$file[2] =~ s/\r\n//g;
$file[3] =~ s/\r\n//g; # Is it the "good" one?
```

It could work. DOS line endings could also be "\r" (not only "\n").

Comment: I generally write `s/[\r\n]+$//` or `s/[\s\r\n]+$//` to tidy up the end of strings, to accommodate any style of line ending.

Comment: `[\s\r\n]` can be more concisely written `\s`, since both `\r` and `\n` are whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid end of line problems is to only capture the characters you're interested in:

```
open (IN, $ARGV[0]);

open (OUT, ">output.txt");
while (<IN>) {
    print OUT "$1\t$2\t$2\n" if /^(\w+)\t\w+\t(\w+)\s*/;
}

close( OUT);
```